# why the div id="wrap" moves when we give margin top to inside div class=''header"

Tags: html, css

Why the div `id="wrap"` moves when we give margin top to inside div class="header"  ?  Please explain why the div moves?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

.header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    d
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden` on wrapper. This will basically prevent margin to collapse.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  overflow:auto;
}

.header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div class="header">
d
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

.header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="header">
   <center> d </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div moves because of the child's margin which is relative positioned.

If you want the `#wrap` div not to be pushed down, set its position to absolute. Try the snippet below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

.header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    d
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about css positions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)